# Scala: mutable HashMap does not update inside for loop

Tags: scala, hashmap, tuples

I have a `var permutedTables = HashMap[List[Int], List[String, String]]` defined globally. I first populate the Hashmap with the keys in a method, which works.

```
print(permutedTables) :
Map(List(1,2,3,4) -> List(),
List(2,4,5,6) -> List(), etc...)
```

The problem occurs when I want to update the values (empty lists) of the HashMap inside a for loop (inside a second method). In other words, I want to add tuples (String, String) in the List() for each key.

```
for(pi_k <- permutedTables.keySet){
      var mask = emptyMask;
      mask = pi_k.foldLeft(mask)((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1'))
      val maskB = Integer.parseInt(mask,2)

      val permutedFP = (intFP & maskB).toBinaryString

     // attempt 1 :
     // permutedTables(pi_k) :+ (url, permutedFP)
     // attempt 2 : 
     // permutedTables.update(pi_k, permutedTables(pi_k):::List((url, permutedFP)))

    }
```

The values do not update. I still have empty lists as values. I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

**EDIT 1:** When I call `print(permutedTables)` after any of the two attempts (inside the loop), the value seem updated, but when I call it outside of the loop, the Lists are empty

**EDIT 2:** The second attempt in my code seems to work now(!). But why does first not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second attempt in my code seems to work now(!). But why does first not work ?

Because what you do in the first case is get a list from `permutedTables`, add an element and throw away the result without storing it back. It would work if you *mutated* the value, but a `List` is immutable. With `List`, you need

```
permutedTables += pi_k -> permutedTables(pi_k) :+ (url, permutedFP)
```

Or, as you saw, `update`.

You can use e.g. `ArrayBuffer` or `ListBuffer` as your value type instead (note that you need `:+=` instead of `:+` to mutate them), and convert to your desired type at the end. This is going to be rather more efficient than appending to the end of the list, unless the lists are quite small!

Finally, note that you generally want *either* `var` or a mutable type, not both at the same time.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I have a similar issue. After seeing the post, I changed my code to use update() while adding to HashMap                                                                                               val tempLHM = new HashMap[String, String] //[edge, vertex]
    pit.foreach { x =>      
      val pp = x.getList(0).iterator() /
      while(pp.hasNext()){
        val pitcol = pp.next().toString().split("\\s+")
        tempLHM.update(pitcol.apply(0).toString(), pitcol.apply(2).toString()) //level0 ppin mapped as edge->vertex
        println(tempLHM.size)} }
    println(tempLHM.size)

Comment: Please not that the first print stmt inside the while loop prints the size correctly but the stmt on the last line prints 0.

Comment: @user1384205 Better ask a separate question, this is unreadable.

Comment: Hi @Alexey Romanov. Please find my question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265498/mutable-hashmap-does-not-update-inside-foreach-loop