# Mutable Hashmap does not update inside foreach loop

Tags: scala

I have a similar issue. After seeing the post, 
[Scala: mutable HashMap does not update inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073804/scala-mutable-hashmap-does-not-update-inside-for-loop/33074730?noredirect=1#comment56241141_33074730)
I changed my code to use update() while adding to HashMap

```
val tempLHM = new HashMap[String, String] //[edge, vertex] 
pit.foreach { x => 
  val pp = x.getList(0).iterator()    
  while(pp.hasNext()){
    val pitcol = pp.next().toString().split("\\s+")  
    tempLHM.update(pitcol.apply(0).toString(), pitcol.apply(2).toString())  
  }
}

//level0 ppin mapped as edge->vertex println(tempLHM.size)} } 
println(tempLHM.size)
```

Please note that the first print stmt inside the while loop prints the size correctly but the stmt on the last line prints 0.

Is this a behavior of foreach function?
Thanks!

UPDATE1: I have imported the following to use mutable hashmap

```
import collection.mutable._
```

UPDATE2: pit is derived the following way

```
val level0Table = hiveContext.read.json(hierarchyMap.get("toplevel").get._2)    
level0Table.registerTempTable("level0"+ hierarchyMap.get("toplevel").get._2)
val pit = level0Table.select("PIT")
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal standalone example that can be executed.

Comment: Please note that Scala hash maps are immutable by default. From your code or isn't clear that you are using a mutable map

Comment: @Archeg. Apologies for the ambiguity. Please find the update in the question.

Comment: It's still not enough. You are talking about the first/last print statement when you have only one. Also you should mention `pit`s type and probably how you are building it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not provide sample data or show the imports you used.  However, the error must be in your input data or the method you are using to parse it.  Here is an example of using a mutable map:

```
object MutableTest extends App {

  val data = List(("a", 1),
                  ("b", 2),
                  ("c", 3),
                  ("a", 0))

  val mutableMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]

  data foreach {tup =>
    mutableMap.update(tup._1, tup._2)  
  }

  println(mutableMap)

}//end object MutableTest
```

The results are as expected:

> Map(b -> 2, a -> 0, c -> 3)

I recommend you output the number of elements in `pit`, output how many elements are in each `pp`, and output `pitcol`.